# Layer Parenting, Make Child Layers Move Along With Parent Layer That's Being Moved by ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, adobe-animate

[image: Screenshots of Character Rig using Layer Parenting and ActionScript Code Results]

I have a Movieclip symbol for a character and within it are multiple symbols of body parts that are linked together using Layer Parenting. Please see my [linked .fla file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nCEatytz3qgkBmIiKA9PJYTbdv9VnQmp/view?usp=sharing) if it helps.

When I rotate one of the body parts such as the torso symbol using the below ActionScript 3.0 code, the torso rotates, but its linked child layers do not rotate with it.

`MovieClip(root).character.torso.rotation = 45;`

How can I get the linked layers to move along with the torso symbol which is being moved with ActionScript?

While I know a workaround would be to place all the other body part symbols inside the "torso" symbol and then rotate it, I would still like to know if layer-parented symbols can be moved with ActionScript while moving the rest of its linked layers with it.

Thank you for any input or assistance with this!

Comment: I say a no. In fact, when I designed a rag doll when I tried to employ inverse kinematics, I used a torso as the character's base, and every limb was attached to the torso by its pivot point, being also a child sprite of torso, so if I turn the torso everything got turned without extra hassle. You'd better do the same, but also provide interface on the character to allow direct alteration of parts' rotation, so that you won't say `character.torso.leftleg.ankle.foot.rotation=0` for example.